# bash mv command in script to rename a file but I got an error

Tags: bash

I have a problem with my script. I want to rename a file but I have an error

```
mv: cannot stat '/home/lidian/Video/dvd.iso': No such file or directory
```

Here is my script:

```
DESTINATION="/home/lidian/Video/dvd.iso"
DESTINATIONFINAL="/home/lidian/Video/"
read -p "what is the name of ISO ? " REP 

mv -t "${DESTINATION}" ${DESTINATIONFINAL}"$REP.iso"
```

Comment: Are you sure the message is with spaces inside? I would expect `mv: failed to access '~/Video/dvd.iso': No such file or directory` without spaces inside the path. Otherwise, it is your script that contains unwanted spaces.

Comment: Does `/home/lidian/Video/` exist?

Comment: Remove option `-t`

Comment: What is the result of `ls /home/lidian/Video/dvd.iso` ? If it is `No such file or directory` you are trying to move a file which does not exist and all of your error messages are coherent. Put a file in that place or change the path to somewhere there is a file to copy.

Comment: I found my error I forgot an s on the Sorry Videos folder

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in bash. Try splitting the first line as follows:

```
DESTINATION="/home/lidian/Video/dvd.iso" 
DESTINATIONFINAL="/home/lidian/Video/" 
read -p "what is the name of ISO ? " REP

mv -t "$DESTINATION" "$DESTINATIONFINAL$REP.iso"
```

I also removed redundant brackets and moved quotes.

Comment: The error message above complains about a path name with spaces inside of it. Have you seen my comment above? Does that message say `mv: failed to access '~/Video/dvd.iso': No such file or directory` or `mv: failed to access '~ / Video / dvd.iso': No such file or directory` (mind the spaces around the bars inside the path name)?

Comment: there is no error space in the error copy

the command mv: cannot stat '/home/lidian/Video/dvd.iso': No such file or directory
does not work

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably you're using `~` tilde in the input. Tilde expansion does not expand/happen inside quotes regardless if it is single or double. Well you do a test on the user input and see if the input is indeed valid.

Comment: I found my error I forgot an s on the Sorry Videos folder